# Trying to display "trade options" to a user based on the games they have in their library. Is there a faster way to do this?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, optimization

I'm trying to build a platform where each user is able to add games to their library, under either the "owned" or "wanted" categories, and then it is the platform's responsibility to find possible trade options.

For example, if user A has game A in their owned list, and user B wants game A, and owns games C and D, then user A will see games C and D under their possible trade options, in return for game A.

Currently, I've implemented this somewhat crudely using too many nested DB queries and I feel like there's a faster way to do this.

The following is what happens every time a user wants to see all of their trade options.

```
let foundUser = await User.findById({_id: req.session.user_id})

let gamesList = []
    //for each game in the users have library, search it up in the game DB and add wantedBy users to an array
    for (let i = 0; i < foundUser.library.have.length; i++){
        let foundGame = await Game.findById({_id: foundUser.library.have[i].gameID})
        //for this game, add each user in the WantedBy List to a local array
        for (let j = 0; j < foundGame.wantedBy.length; j++){
            //for each of these users, use their have list to build the trade object
            let newFoundUser = await User.findById({_id: foundGame.wantedBy[j]})

            //check if the other user wants the game for the same platform as foundUser.library.have[i].platform
            console.log(newFoundUser)
            console.log(foundGame.wantedBy)
            let platformMatch = newFoundUser.library.want.find(game => (game.platform === foundUser.library.have[i].platform) && (game.gameID == foundUser.library.have[i].gameID))
            
            if (platformMatch){

                for (let k = 0; k < newFoundUser.library.have.length; k++){
                    //for each of these games in the other users have list, make a trade object
                    let newFoundGame = await Game.findById({_id: newFoundUser.library.have[k].gameID})
                    let tradeObject = {
                        gameOffered: newFoundUser.library.have[k].gameID,
                        gameOfferedBackImg: newFoundGame.backImg,
                        gameOfferedPlatform: newFoundUser.library.have[k].platform,
                        gameOfferedTitle: newFoundGame.title,
                        inReturnForTitle: foundGame.title,
                        inReturnForPlatform: foundUser.library.have[i].platform,
                        inReturnFor: foundGame._id,
                        otherUserID: newFoundUser._id
                    }
                    gamesList.push(tradeObject)
                }
            }
        }
        
    }


res.render('trade', {gamesList: gamesList, mainUser: foundUser._id})
```

The nested loops and DB queries make this really slow, especially if the no. of users and the no. games in their library increases.

The following are the DB schemas:

The User Schema:

```
username: {
    type: String,
    required: ['true', 'Username cannot be blank'],
},
email: {
    type: String,
    required: ['true', 'Email cannot be blank']
},
password: {
    type: String,
    required: ['true', 'Password cannot be blank'],
},
phoneNum: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true
},
isVerified: false,
address: {
    city: String,
    area: String,
    street: String,
    nearestLandmark: String
},
verificationCode: String,
library: {
    have: [{
        gameID: String,
        platform: String
    }],
    want: [{
        gameID: String,
        platform: String
    }]
},
notifications: [
    {
        dateTime: Date,
        message: String
    }
]
```

})

The Game Schema:

```
const gameSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
title: String,
backImg: String,
wantedBy: [String]
```

})

Any help optimising this would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Your example is somewhat ambiguous: User B might be willing to trade _both C and D_ in exchange for A, or they might be willing to trade _either C or D_ in exchange for A. Do you allow for both possibilities?

Comment: That's also accounted for, I just didn't include it in the example because it happens after the trade options have been parsed but basically, user A will send a trade request to user B, either for game C or game D. It is then upto user B whether they want to accept or not.

Comment: You should specify in more detail what constitutes a "trade option". In your example, user A is given trade options even though they do not want any game at all. If user A wanted something, would they get fewer or more trade options?

Comment: Ah my apologies, I'll try to make it clearer. Yes, user A will see trade options even when they have nothing under their "wanted" list because the options they see are based off of what they own, not what they want. Adding or removing games from user A's wanted list will not affect user A's trade options, but it will affect the visibility of user A's owned games under other users' trade options.

Comment: Essentially, user A keeping their 'wanted' list empty would mean they cannot *receive* any trade requests, but they can send some, because they have a game in their owned list that is wanted by other users.